# AngularJs UI-Select change to input-lg

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

Does anyone know how to add the input-lg class to my ui-select directive?  I am using the angularJs ui-select with the bootstrap theme.

I have tried

```
<ui-select ng-model="link.closer.data" class="input-lg">
```

I have also looked at the select.js file and tried adding input-lg but nothing seems to work

Comment: If you inspect the ui-select, does it have the class, or is it removed?

Comment: The `uiSelect` directive has `replace:true` in it's config. Anything you add to that element will be removed. The docs and code have no way of adding custom classes from a quick scan over.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it with css.

```
.ui-select-bootstrap>.ui-select-match>.btn,
.form-control:focus {
    height: 46px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `uiSelect` directive has `replace:true` in it's config. Anything you add to that element will be removed. The docs and code have no way of adding custom classes from a quick scan over.

However the implementation does have a concept of themes. This is defined as an attribute on the directives element. There are a number of themes built in.

- bootstrap
- select2
- selectize

For example to use these themes you would use:

```
// Bootstrap
<ui-select ng-model="link.closer.data" theme="bootstrap">

// Select 2
<ui-select ng-model="link.closer.data" theme="select2">

// Selectize
<ui-select ng-model="link.closer.data" theme="selectize">
```

If you look at the code that loads in the templates, you'll see the following in the `templateUrl` property.

```
templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
    var theme = tAttrs.theme || uiSelectConfig.theme;
    return theme + (angular.isDefined(tAttrs.multiple) ? 
        '/select-multiple.tpl.html' : 
        '/select.tpl.html');
}
```

So angular will load the correct theme based on the directive attribute or use the default value from the configuration.

As a workaround, you could create your own theme by building the templates for them.

```
// Note the location for my theme is "mytheme/select.tpl.html"
// making my theme name: "mytheme"
angular.module("customSelect")
    .run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache {
        $templateCache.put("mytheme/select.tpl.html",
            "<p>my custom html here<\/p>";
    ]});
```

An easy way to do this is to open up the `ui-select/dist/select.js` scroll to the bottom. Copy all the templateCache declarations for bootstrap. Paste them into your own project and modify the theme name and the html, including your class `input-lg`.

Now include your theme name as the theme in the directive.

```
<ui-select ng-model="link.closer.data" theme="mytheme">
```

And to use the native

```
<ui-select ng-model="link.closer.data">
```

Or

```
<ui-select ng-model="link.closer.data" theme="bootstrap">
```

Now you have full control over the HTML generated by the directive including all classnames etc without modifying the core code.